# Android: Fetching an XML from a web service: Threads

Tags: android

Fetching an XML from a web service in background and displaying a progress bar in front while the xml is being downloaded in Android

Comment: That is a statement and not a question.

Comment: How to do it? Any one ? pls Help

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at:

http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/painless-threading.html

and:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

For info on how to perform work in the background.

In short:

Subclass AsyncTask and override doInBackground(Params... params). In that method you should do the communication with the server and download the xml. You can call publishProgress(Progress... values) to have the UI thread run the method  onProgressUpdate(Progress... values) in your AsyncTask. In that method you can define how to update the progressbar.

Cheers
// Emil H